# How to overcome limitation imposed to mobile visitors?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am making a client which will allow usage of multiple websites within Android app. Some websites disable comments when the website is visited by mobile users.

I changed user agent string to `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"` (taken from my desktop browser), but the commenting is still disabled.

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(uaLinux);
webview.loadUrl(url);
setContentView(webview);
```

Namely, the external website (with new user agent string set) does not detect a mobile user as mobile. But pressing the Button comment, does not publish comment at all. visiting the same page with a desktop browser, does not have this issue.

How can this website still detect my app as a mobile? What else I can change?

To remind, all I changed is a user agent string to hide myself as a mobile visitor.

Comment: Why would anyone use your app, if it is just a bunch of bookmarks which even lead you to the wrong version of sites. They spend a lot of time in building a proper experience for mobile users, and you create an app - which takes away that experience...  The sites that do not support some features for mobile, probably have some decent reason internally not to do so. Little you can do to fight it.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn Users want mobile comments more than anything in this app and site owner do not allow it in spite of their requests. That is why I am 100% sure they will like it even thou it will be an ugly approach.